# Passing array to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, arrays

Is it possible to pass an array as an argument from a C# code to a WCF web service?

I'm still new to all this.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Of course it's possible. Why not just try it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes absolutely. Your service contract could look like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFooService
{
    void Foo(int[] intArray);
}
```

If you want to pass an array of some custom type this type needs to be marked with `[DataContract]` and its properties with `[DataMember]`.