# Bind datagrid to empty itemsource?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

hey iam  doin silvelright 4 app.

I have datagrid with 3 coloums say Name,Age,EmpId,

The datagrid is **not binded** to itemsource.(Will have no rows intially)

The user can add new rows and finally save the grid on a button click.
At the moment of button click i need to get all data from the datatgrid and pass to WCF..

Is it possible to assign datagrid empty itemsource?if so how?

how do i store these data from datagrid.. collections or datatable??

Could someone help me out ..i am new to this..
please provide example if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)

You have to bind your datagrid to the collection using ItemsSource. Trust me, it will be easier.

Create a class like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public int EmpId {get;set;}
}
```

Then, create a ObservableCollection<Person> and bind it to your dataGrid ItemsSource. On a button click, add the code:

```
myObservableCollection.Add(new Person() { });
```

this will add a empty row on your grid so you can fill it with some data.

This way you will have a observableCollection with all your data displayed on a dataGrid. You could process/serialize it and send to the server. If you have a specific question about that I suggest you create another question. [RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/get-started-with-wcf-ria-services) could do this kind of thing easily.

Comment: could you tell me how send myobservablecollection object to wcf?

Comment: I do not know if you could pass it directly but you could call ToArray(). Look [here:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889143/passing-array-to-wcf-service)

Comment: PS.: You would need to have the "Person" class defined on the server, on your WCF service.